# For a convex function, why does lower semicontinuity imply weak lower semicontinuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I have come across the statement that, for a convex function, all notions of lower semicontinuity are equivalent. That is: weak lower, sequential lower, and weak sequential lower semicontinuity are all equilvalent to lower semicontinuity. I can't find a proof for this, can anyone supply one?

Many thanks,
A.

Comment: The set $[f \leq \lambda] $ is convex and strongly closed. Then it is weakly closed.

Comment: how do you get that result?

Comment: That convex and strongly closed sets are weakly closed is a consequence of a geometric form of the Hahn-Banach theorem. That $[f \leq \lambda]$ is convex is a consequence of convexity of $f$. That $[f \leq \lambda]$ is closed is strong l.s.c. of $f$.

Comment: For a general Banach space, weak sequential lower semicontinuity is not equivalent to weak lower semicontinuity. If you further assume $[f \leq \lambda]$ is bounded for all $\lambda$ and the dual is separable (or something resembling this), this should be enough.

Comment: Ah ok I'll try and deduce that from Hahn-Banach. Thanks :)